# An Object Reference is Required For ToDoList.MainForm

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to make a ToDo list program that has multiple forms. There is a main form with a listbox that will contain the titles of all the tasks, and a separate form that the user will use to type in the details of the task (title, description, priority, etc) which will be added to the listbox in the other form. However, when I try to add the user's data from the second form into the first using this method:

```
MainForm.AddToForm(newTask);
```

I get the problem: 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property ToDoList.MainForm.AddToForm(string[])

Can someone please direct me as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to suggest that `MainForm` or `ToDoList` (or both) is the name of a class instead of an instance of a class. Unless an object or method within that class is marked `static`, you cannot access it through the class itself - you must access it through an instance. As an example:

```
//creation of an instance of Foo
Foo foo = new Foo();

//call static method belonging to Foo
Foo.StaticFn();

//call to member method of Foo (not marked static)
//only can be used on a valid instance
foo.MemberFn();
```